# D3.js idles between each mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, dom-events

I am having an issue with d3.js when I try to zoom in and out on a graph. The zoom is very slow and laggy. I am trying to debug by using the profiling tool (Opera/Chrome). I was expecting my zoom callback function to be the limiting factor but it turns out there is a lot of idle time between each mousewheel scroll events.[image: D3 is idling for 1s between each scrolls]

Motus operandum: I start the profiling, then give a big sharp scroll on the mousewheel (5sec on the graph). The graph lags for several seconds(from 5sec to 8.5sec on the graph) then calls my zoom callback periodically (from 8.5 to 14sec on the graph). I checked the stack calls and all my zooming callbacks are executed in order, synchronously, which makes me think the are done executing during the idle time. I think the profiler does not record some of the system/browser calls and qualifies those as idle, so I tried using interruptions ( event.preventDefault() etc...) to make sure nothing was executed on zoomend. It improved a little bit the performance, but there is still a lot of idle time:

[image: It starts off nicely but slows down]

Can someone please help me figure out why there is so much idle time?

Here is my relevant code:

- without interruption

  ```
   d3Zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                  .x(element.self.xScale)
                  .y(element.self.yScale)
                  .scaleExtent([0.99, Infinity])
                  .on("zoom", semanticZoom)
                  .on("zoomend", updateSelection);
  ```
- with interruption

  ```
   var delayTimer=0;
   d3Zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                  .x(xScale)
                  .y(yScale)
                  .scaleExtent([0.99, Infinity])
                  .on("zoom", semanticZoom)
                  .on("zoomstart", function () {
                      //prevent recalculating heavyCalculations too often
                      window.clearTimeout(delayTimer);                            
                      var evt = e ? e : window.event;
                      return cancelDefaultAction(evt);
                  })
                  .on("zoomend", function () {
                      // only start heavy calculations if user hasn't zoomed for 0.75sec
                      delayTimer = window.setTimeout(updateSelection, 750);
                  });

    function cancelDefaultAction(e) {
                  var evt = e ? e : window.event;
                  if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
                  evt.returnValue = false;
                  return false;
              }`
  ```

EDIT: Here is an example of working code. Both semanticZoom and update selection are more complex in my project than in this example but they involve custom AngularJS directives, d3 brushes, warped geometry, aggregation etc... I have cropped semanticZoom to just perform an enter/exit/update pattern based on a quadtree (it might behave funny in this the example, but it's just to show the kind of operations I do). UpdateSelection updates the visible data to an angular directive to perform calculations (various statistics etc...). I did not populate it here but it is not actually very intensive.

```js
var size = 100;

var dataset = d3.range(10).map(function(d, idx) {
  return {
    x: d3.random.normal(size / 2, size / 4)(),
    y: d3.random.normal(size / 2, size / 4)(),
    uuid: idx
  };
});

//
// Init Scales
//

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, size])
  .range([0, 100]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, size])
  .range([0, 100]);

//
// Init Axes
//

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(10)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickSize(-size);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(10)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(-size);

//
// Init Zoom
//

var d3Zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(xScale)
  .y(yScale)
  .scaleExtent([0.99, Infinity])
  .on("zoom", semanticZoom)
  .on("zoomend", updateSelection);

var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(dataset);


//------------------------ Callbacks --------------------------------

function semanticZoom() {

  var s = 1;
  var t = [0, 0];
  if (d3.event) {
    s = (d3.event.scale) ? d3.event.scale : 1;
    t = (d3.event.translate) ? d3.event.translate : [0, 0];
  }

  // set zoom boundaries
  // center of the zoom in svg coordinates
  var center = [(size / 2 - t[0]) / s, (size / 2 - t[1]) / s];
  // half size of the window in svg coordinates
  var halfsize = size / (2 * s);
  // top left corner in svg coordinates
  var tl = [center[0] - halfsize, center[1] - halfsize];
  // bottom right corner in svg coordinates
  var br = [center[0] + halfsize, center[1] + halfsize];

  /*

   //
   // Constrain zoom
   //

   if (!(tl[0] > -10 &&
      tl[1] > -10 &&
      br[0] < size + 10 &&
      br[1] < size + 10)) {

    // limit zoom-window corners
    tl = [Math.max(0, tl[0]), Math.max(0, tl[1])];
    br = [Math.min(size, br[0]), Math.min(size, br[1])];
    // get restrained center
    center = [(tl[0] + br[0]) / 2, (tl[1] + br[1]) / 2];
    // scale center
    t = [size / 2 - s * center[0], size / 2 - s * center[1]];

    // update svg
    svg.transition()
     .duration(1)
     .call( d3Zoom.translate(t).event );

   }
   */

  //
  // Store zoom extent
  //

  d3Zoom.extent = [tl, br];
  d3Zoom.scaleFactor = s;
  d3Zoom.translation = t;

  //
  // Update some heavy duty stuff 
  // (create a quadtree, search that quadtree and update an attribute for the elements found)
  //

  // Prune non visible data
  var displayedData = search(quadtree,
    d3Zoom.extent[0][0], d3Zoom.extent[0][1],
    d3Zoom.extent[1][0], d3Zoom.extent[1][1]);

  redrawSubset(displayedData);

  //
  // Update axes
  //

  d3.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  d3.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

}

function redrawSubset(subset) {

  //Attach new data

  var elements = d3.select(".data_container")
    .selectAll(".datum")
    .data(subset, function(d) {
      return d.uuid;
    });

  //enter

  elements.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "datum")
    .attr("r", 1)
    .style("fill", "black");

  //exit

  elements.exit().remove();

  //update

  elements.attr("transform", ScaleData);

}


function updateSelection() {
  // some not so heavy duty stuff

}

function ScaleData(d) {
  return "translate(" + [xScale(d.x), yScale(d.y)] + ")";
}

//
// search quadtree
//

function search(qt, x0, y0, x3, y3) {
  var pts = [];
  qt.visit(function(node, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var p = node.point;

    if ((p) && (p.x >= x0) && (p.x <= x3) && (p.y >= y0) && (p.y <= y3)) {
      pts.push(p);
    }

    return x1 >= x3 || y1 >= y3 || x2 < x0 || y2 < y0;
  });

  return pts;
}



//------------------------- DOM Manipulation -------------------------  

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", size)
  .attr("height", size)
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "data_container")
  .call(d3Zoom);



svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", size)
  .attr("height", size)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all");



var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset, function(d) {
    return d.uuid;
  }).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1)
  .attr("class", "datum")
  .attr("transform", ScaleData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

SemanticZoom and UpdateSelection have both been unit tested and run in times comparable to the profiler graphs above (50-100ms) for large datasets.

Comment: Make an isolated, working example focusing on your problem and see if you get the same problem.  If you can do that and you still see the problem, then post the working example as a snippet.  If you do that and don't see the same problem, then look elsewhere for the cause.

Comment: When I make an easy example, of a d3 zoom, on a graph with little data, everything works perfectly well. When the dataset gets bigger (50k-100k points), it starts to lag. This is not surprising as SVG does not scale well for very well for big datasets.

This is why I am trying to optimize my callback functions. But I am having trouble understanding where I should focus since the profiler tells me my functions execute pretty quickly (~90ms which should be around 12-15fps). Instead I have 1fps or less and a lot of idle time.

Comment: Can you post a working example with a bogus data generator to get the scale without the bloat? I can help check it out if you do that. Otherwise I'm not really keen to invest all that effort to set up a working model...

Comment: maybe the bottleneck is not the CPU but the graphics card?

Comment: @PatrickKlug Would you know how to make sure and how to optimize code for that?-----------------------  
@ CoolBlue Here is a sample code that performs with idles on my computer on large datasets. I understand that without the real semanticZoom and the real UpdateSelection callback it might be hard to debug, but those are complex functions so I had to simplify them a lot. I am actually more looking for ideas of possible origins for the "idle" behaviour. Could it be OS based? In which case would Window.requestAnimationFrame() be helpful? Or is it solely code based?

Comment: I'd recommend you use deeper profilers that look at HDD, CPU and GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a few zeros to the circle count and make the svg big enough to be useful, then the zoom slows down to what you describe. But it's hardly surprising since it has a bunch of work to do visiting the nodes in the quad tree and writing to the DOM to manage the svg components.  I don't understand why you are transforming individual circles instead of grouping them and transforming the g.  If you did that then you could just let the svg element clip the image and avoid all of the svg overheads which would free up 75% of your budget.  If the only purpose of the quad tree is to figure out which nodes are visible then that would also be eliminated.

A key observation I guess is that this profile is markedly different from the pics you posted, judging by the profile of your pics, they seem to be all about the quad tree and the rest is idle time. It would be interesting to see your cpu and gpu loading during the profile.

[image]

You can eliminate the need for deleting and re-writing nodes by using a clip path, that way the only overhead is re-writing the transform attributes.
There was also a problem with your search.  There is a much simpler way to do it that works fine and that is to use the `#linear.invert(y)` method of the scale.
Both these are addressed in the sample code below...

```js
  var size = 500;

  var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  d3.select("#clipButton").on("click", (function() {
    var clipped = false, clipAttr = [null, "url(#clip)"],
      value = ["clip", "brush"];
    return function() {
      circles
        .attr("clip-path", clipAttr[(clipped = !clipped, +clipped)]);
      this.value = value[+clipped];
    }
  })());

  var dataset = d3.range(1000).map(function(d, idx) {
    return {
      x: d3.random.normal(100 / 2, 100 / 4)(),
      y: d3.random.normal(100 / 2, 100 / 4)(),
      uuid: idx
    };
  });

  //
  // Init Scales
  //

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, width])
      .nice(10);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([height, 0])
    .nice(10);

  //
  // Init Axes
  //

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(10)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(-height);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .ticks(10)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(-width);

  //
  // Init Zoom
  //

  var d3Zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xScale)
    .y(yScale)
    .scaleExtent([0.99, Infinity])
    .on("zoom", semanticZoom)
//    .on("zoomend", updateSelection);

  var Quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()
    .x(function(d){return d.x})
    .y(function(d){return d.y});
    quadtree = Quadtree(dataset);

  //------------------------ Callbacks --------------------------------

  function semanticZoom() {

    var s = 1;
    var t = [0, 0];
    if (d3.event) {
      s = (d3.event.scale) ? d3.event.scale : 1;
      t = (d3.event.translate) ? d3.event.translate : [0, 0];
    }

    var tl = [xScale.invert(0), yScale.invert(height)];
    var br = [xScale.invert(width), yScale.invert(0)];

    //
    // Store zoom extent
    //

    d3Zoom.extent = [tl, br];
    d3Zoom.scaleFactor = s;
    d3Zoom.translation = t;

    //
    // Update some heavy duty stuff
    // (create a quadtree, search that quadtree and update an attribute for the elements found)
    //

    // Prune non visible data
    var displayedData = search(quadtree, d3Zoom.extent);

    markSubset(displayedData, circle);
    updateSelection(circle);
    //
    // Update axes
    //

    d3.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    d3.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

  };
  function markSubset(data, nodes){
    var marked = nodes.data(data, function(d){return d.uuid;});
    marked.enter();
    marked.classed("visible", true);
    marked.exit().classed("visible", false);
  }
  function updateSelection(elements) {
    // some not so heavy duty stuff
    elements.attr("transform", ScaleData);

  }

  function ScaleData(d) {
    return "translate(" + [xScale(d.x), yScale(d.y)] + ")";
  }

  //
  // search quadtree
  //

  function search(qt, extent) {
    var pts = [],
        x0=extent[0][0], y0=extent[0][1],
      x3=extent[1][0], y3=extent[1][1];
    qt.visit(function(node, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      var p = node.point;

      if ((p) && (p.x >= x0) && (p.x <= x3) && (p.y >= y0) && (p.y <= y3)) {
        pts.push(p);
      }

      return x1 >= x3 || y1 >= y3 || x2 < x0 || y2 < y0;
    });

    return pts;
  }

  //------------------------- DOM Manipulation -------------------------

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "data_container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(d3Zoom),

    plotSurface = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style({"fill": "steelblue", opacity: 0.8})
    .style("pointer-events", "all"),

    gX = svg.append("g")            // Add the X Axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis),

    gY = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis),

    clipRect = svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height),

    circles = svg.append("g")/*
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")*/,
    circle = circles.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.uuid;
      });

  circle.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("class", "datum")
      .attr("transform", ScaleData);

  semanticZoom();
```

```css
    svg {
      outline: 1px solid red;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    .axis path {
      stroke: #000;
    }

    .axis line {
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-opacity: .5;
    }
    .axis path {
      fill: none;
    }
    .axis text {
      font-size: 8px;
    }
    .datum {
      fill: #ccc;
    }
    .datum.visible {
      fill: black;
    }
    #clipButton {
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<input id="clipButton" type="button" value="clip">
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight.
The quadtree is used for both visibility and brush selection (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214).
I am going to try and change the transforms to a group to free CPU but I don't think I know how to do that for semantic zooming. If I apply the same transform to all datum, would'nt that give me a geometric zoom instead (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999)?

Comment: @Titi Yes, I see what you mean, I hadn't got my brain around what semantic zoom means.  But OK, you can still avoid a lot of overhead by using a clip path. See my updated answer...

Comment: Ok, feel free to accept the answer ;). To be honest, your method of removing and re-writing nodes has advantages. My method has the same lag regardless of how many nodes are included in the zoom level but yours gets more responsive the more you zoom in (I'm talking about 10k+ nodes). I tried disconnecting the un-included nodes by setting them to opacity zero (actually, I didn't try display none...), in other words not bothering to delete them but arranging so they wouldn't be displayed and your method was still much better at large zooms.

Comment: And oh, ok. Your talking about `xScale.invert`. Yes, it's nice when you find that the code is already there in d3 and its worth looking, coz it almost always is there.

Comment: You are correct: At large zooms it doesn't perform extraordinarily well at large zooms but prunes the DOM very nicely on closeups. Therefore, I am thinking using a mix of algorithm: start pruning when zoom level is high enough, but just clip for small zooms.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, it's a bit of a balancing act. For me 1,000 nodes is fine and 10,000 is marginal. I also saw the delays you reported when there were 10,000 to 100,000 nodes and I'm sure they are due to browser activity because the length of the gaps is related to the number of nodes. I didn't see Idle though, only program in the gaps..

Comment: Yeah. When I see program, I don't really mind. I interpret it as a mix of OS/browser work. Idle is more of a problem. I think I need to redesign some parts of my data flow. the problem with javascript is that everything is synchronous. maybe if I add some Parallel.js it might help solve that.

However. I am very much afraid to enter debugging hell if I have to manage thread sync between my AngularJS $digests, my d3.js context and whatever context Parallel.js needs.

Comment: Two interesting observations: 1. The data doesn't change (or maybe it does in your real application, but not often) and 2. The quadtree algorithm can be split in 4. It's not an order of magnitude saving but the quadtree could be implemented as 4 webworkers. I've successfully run standard d3 in a webworker, you just need to have some objects for it to interrogate on startup to convince it its in a DOM. The only catch is serialisation overherhead (if transferable objects are not available) but the data doesn't change in this case, so that's not a problem.

Comment: By the way, you also need to sort the nodes (re-order the DOM elements) by their .uuid when you are writing them back on zoom out, otherwise you get concentric rectangular artifacts and anyway, you loose object constancy.